# Batch Import ContentVersion data via the REST endpoint

Tags: apex, batch, rest, contentversion

I am trying to upload a large amount of photos for Salesforce via the `/sobjects/ContentVersion` REST endpoint. Currently I am able to use this endpoint to upload one photo at a time. Is there a way to use this endpoint to upload multiple photos per api call instead of one at a time? Is there another endpoint I should be using to batch upload `ContentVersion` data?

Much appreciation!

Comment: check out the composite resource for SFDC REST

Comment: Thank you! This lead me in the right direction and I found this post showing how to do this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244193/salesforce-standard-api-composite-tree-resource

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @cropredy's suggestion I was able to find this post which shows how to use the SF composite tree to upload multiple content versions in 1 api call: [Salesforce Standard API - Composite Tree resource](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244193/salesforce-standard-api-composite-tree-resource)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.